# Clear quest - Need to query Named lists

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearquest, clearcase-automation

My requirement:
i need to add a new value to the Named lists(in CQ, edit ->Named lists ->Build Number) using cq perl.
Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

Got it, Thanks.
If any one is looking for answer:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cqhelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearquest.apiref.doc%2Ftopics%2Fc_database_mthds.htm

Comment: Version 8 is newer: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cqhelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearquest.apiref.doc%2Ftopics%2Fc_database_mthds.htm